# Web client FTP server-like solution using S3

Tags: ftp, amazon-s3

I have been tasked with setting up an FTP server to share files with our clients. I would like to forego the traditional FTP server/FTP client type of setup for one that would use S3 as the backend with a web interface for users to upload files.

I could spend the time to develop something fairly quickly, but I would think that this has been developed already...

Answer (score 1):

You could use IAM to created limited S3 policies for users. Then have users use free tools such as S3 Organizer on FF, or the AWS Management Console to use S3.